# Limit geocoding to specific AdministrativeAreaName

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Is there any clever way to tell google geocoding api to narrow its search to a specific AdministrativeAreaName (or by any other criteria i.e. Country, SubAdministrativeArea etc) or would I have to manually sort results that are returned to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can specify the region in the URL when you are making the [Geocoding Request](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)

Comment: As GoG says, see the documentation.  You can provide a simple lat/lon bounding box (which isn't an administrative area) or a country code (but not other administrative areas).  If you don't provide a country code, results are biased to the country of the IP the request is coming from, according to the Google documentation.